# Confusing binary numbers

Tags: binary, decimal, data-conversion, twos-complement, ones-complement

I had a doubt which is confusing me,
Isn't 1101(base 2) = 13 (base 10) or is it 1101 (base 2) = -5 (base 10) ?

I am assuming that when we use two's complement method then we use a negative integer, but when we generally use the integer then it is positive. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: you may want to consider using google first: https://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/

Comment: it is both, depending on interpretation, this is why we have signed and unsigned types in some languages or different commands (like mul/imul in x86 asm)

Comment: @HowardP  The link which you provided gives "***ERROR: invalid characters in input" as output.

Comment: @SahilSilare I just used it correctly and it provided me with the answer 13. Be sure you're putting the correct numbers in the correct area.